# No puedo insertar datos desde mi pagina de asp.net a mi base de datos de sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

[image: Esta es la tabla usuario]
Cuando ejecuto y presiono el `boton` de registar solo hace un pequeño refresh y no hace nada mas

```
        public partial class registro : System.Web.UI.Page{
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    //boton de incio de sesion 
    protected void BtnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" INSERT INTO Usuarios(Nombre,Apellido,Telefono,cedula,Correo,Constraseña) values (@Nombre,@Apellido,@Telefono,@cedula,@Correo,@Contraseña)", con);


             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", txtNombre.Text.Trim());
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellido", txtApellido.Text.Trim());
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", txtTelefono.Text.Trim());
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedula", txtCedula.Text.Trim());
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Correo", txtCorreo.Text.Trim());
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contraseña", txtContraseña.Text.Trim());

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (cmd != null)
            {
                string script = "alert('Datos Guardados');";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Exito", script, true);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            string script = "alert('Datos No Guardados');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Error", script, true);
        }

    }
```

Este es el error que me sale en el Exception

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código que muestras parece correcto, revisa la cadena de conexión, pero antes, pon un punto de interrupción en el primer `try` y mira si llega jasta ahí.

Comment: hice lo que dijiste y ejecute por partes y me di cuenta que deja de funcionar al llegar a la condicion. Pero creo que una vez llegado ahi ya deberia haber instertado los datos no?

Comment: Si ha llegado a `if (cmd != null)` debería haber insertado correctamente, a no ser que la conexión esté mal e inserte en otra base de datos de don tu lo revisas.

Comment: @RogerTorné antes de cambiar a otra base de datos intente de nuevo y me di cuenta de que no llega, se queda en `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: ¿Cómo que se queda? ¿Salta luego al `catch`? Si es así, es que hay un error con la tabla o sus campos. O bien no existen en la base de datos de destino o alguna otra cosa pasa. Pon un punto de interrupción en el `catch` y cuando se pare, mira el valor del error poniéndote encima de `Exception`

Comment: @RogerTorné Arriba agregue una imagen con mi tabla usuario

Comment: Asegurate que los datos insertados no excedan el límite de cada campo y que los numéricos lo sean de verdad. Pero mejor que mires el error como te comentaba más arriba

Comment: Creo que encontre el problema. Estaba probando con otro proyecto el cual si me funciona y por lo que parace no me deja insertar por los campos que tengo en null, es deci en el otro proyecto que si me funciona agregue dos columnas en null a la cual no le insertaba nada y cuando lo ejecutaba me dejaba de funcionar